# How to XMLReader and Deserialize in java

Tags: java, android, xml, deserialization, xmlreader

I have a XML File that have attribute on every tag .

**point**:my xml don't have any value of tag beacuse exits on the attribute on tags

some tags :

```
<Videos>
 <Video VideoID="1000000" StoredFilename="fcce6a62-7f87-45c1-afc1-31b624268118.mp4" VideoName="Test"  />
 <Video VideoID="1000001" StoredFilename="f4f703e6-552e-42a9-a262-448d5615d843.mp4" VideoName="test1"  />
 <Video VideoID="1000002" StoredFilename="4d59be7a-7e32-487c-a46d-9fe0271f770b.mp4" VideoName="test2"  />
 </Videos>
```

How to Deserialize its on java classes.thanks

Comment: You should try something before you ask on this forum. I bet google has quite a few examples on the issue. Even this forum has a number of duplicates to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149776/how-to-deserialize-java-objects-from-xml

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I am in agreement with Qben.  I would also like to add: When you ask a question, make sure that you make what you are asking as clear as possible.  If no one can understand what you are asking, you likely will not get any responses.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution of using DOM or SAX parser.
Try it

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "add your class's full qualified class name   here" );
      Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
      Object o = u.unmarshal( xmlSource );

You can cast the Object o to your type I think. Please refer this. http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html

Comment: thanks friends.I used this Example And My Proble Soloved     http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example

Comment: jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example this example just one parent tag.in my xml contain some paret tag.How to brintNext when a tag is finished

Comment: Put your xml structure