# Generic solution to deserialize XML Java Objects?

Tags: java, xml, database

Is there any generic solution out there to be used when deserializing XML into Java Objects and to the database afterwards? Without the need of generating and recompiling specific POJO's every time?

I'm hunting for something that's capable to deserialize an XML like this:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <title>My Super Book</title>
    <authors>
      <author>
        <name>Thom A.</name>
      </author>
      ...
    </authors>
  </book>
  ...
</books>
```

Into generic Java ArrayLists and HashMaps which keep the relationships between the objects somehow. Maybe like the following:

```
books = [{
  title: "My Super Book",
  authors: [{
    name: "Thom A."
  },...]
},...]
```

And afterwards persist these to the database into the tables `books` and `authors`.

**UPDATE:**
The XML structure is **NOT** known at compile time. It has to be discovered at runtime. So this will end up in a generic import which can be used for different kind of XML structures without the need of recompiling or adjusting the code of the program.

**UPDATE 2:**
The database structure is given and can be taken into account at compile time. However, a solution which gives us the flexibility to change the mapping between xml and database at runtime would be preferred.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4149776/2112089

Comment: check eclipse link jaxb compiler http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts008.htm

Comment: @JFPicard I've already searched for nearly 2 days for a possible solution before posting here. I've looked at JAXB, JIXB and XStream. JAXB and JIXB enforces me to generate classes and compile them in order of deserializing the XML to work. XStream seems to be capable of parsing XML into HashMaps and ArrayLists - but I can't figure out a way of keeping the relationships. Therefore I'm not sure if it's the right tool for the job and I'm running out of ideas now. How should I edit my question in order to reflect the need of a dynamic and generic XML deserialization at runtime...?

Comment: @DeepakKumar can't see how binding jaxb to json would solve the need of deserializing xml w/o previously generated classes (like the employee one in your link). What I'm missing?

Comment: @MarcoBetschart I missed to read that part (Without the need of generating and recompiling specific POJO's every time).. So I have deleted my comment.. :)

Comment: @Pascal How would the accepted answer `... that is mapped to java objets with JAXB ...` work? In other words: How do I map the xml to generic ArrayLists & HashMaps using JAXB?

Comment: Reading your first comment, I understand that you don't know the content of the XML before you parse it. Is that it ? If I'm understanding this corretly, you want to parse XML, discover its content, generate classes from what you've discovered, convert that content to HashMaps and ArrayLists and then push it to a database ?

Comment: @Pascal you're right. I don't care if I have to provide some sort of xml binding configuration etc to the programm. I just don't want to develop & recompile the app for every different XML which should be imported.

Comment: OK, to answer your comment to JFPicard, "How should I edit my question in order to reflect the need of a dynamic and generic XML deserialization at runtime...?", I suggest you add something along the lines of "ie. the XML structure isn't know at compile time, it must be discovered at runtime" to your first paragraph.

Comment: @Pascal thanks for your suggestion. Question updated.

Comment: it's strange you don't know the content(structure) of xml but you do have DB model defined? or you don't?

Comment: `XStream seems to be capable of parsing XML into HashMaps and ArrayLists - but I can't figure out a way of keeping the relationships` - keeping which relationships?

Comment: @Mil4n I do have an existing database structure. The reason for this is we'd like to import data from different data providers which all have different XML structures. And we don't want to programm for each one a different import. EDIT: And cool would be if you don't know the database structure at compile time either - so you're fully free to import any XML into any database ;)

Comment: @bezmax the relationships between the nodes. Or in other words: The information which enables the parsed objects to be stored in a relational database (with primary keys and foreign keys).

Comment: But they must have common structures in them that represent your domain model, otherwise you will be pattern guessing. If they are SO different and have nothing to do with your target data structure you might have to write transformations for each of them.

Comment: @Mil4n let's assume they contain all the common structures which represent our domain model, but the structure varies. How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at JAX-B, java <-> XML bindings. This allows you to transform xml files into java objects. You can also fire java objects into a database using hibernate or JPA.

JAX-B
[click](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

HIBERNATE
[click](http://hibernate.org/)

JPA
[click](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/)

**EDIT:**
You are asking for such specific functionality that I personally do not think you will find very quickly in any major library or framework. I do not know if such a thing already exists. On the subject of changing the database mapping on the go:

You could read the mapping in a certain format saved in a file everytime you fire a database command. con is that you would gain a little overhead from this, pro is that files can be adjusted runtime, thus your mapping described in a file could be adjusted runtime. This however would require a lot of work from your side.

On the subject of discovering what is inside of your xml file. You have to ask yourself, in which depth may the content of this file vary ? It is not a bad practice to engineer your system in such a manner that it expects files to be of a certain structure. (take a look at XSD files). Trying to design a system that dynamically discovers xml and checks if it is compatible with your database seems to be a little out of your scope here.

Your best guess would be to write a custom DOM / SAX parser which fires command to your database according to some mapping, which you could possibly describe in a file which you can adjust runtime.

Comment: I'm searching for a solution, where the XML structure is not known at compile time. As far as I know this solution does not work at runtime?

Comment: Welp, that makes things more complicated. You would have to write your own parser. You could have a look at JAVA SAX parsers or DOM parsers. I do assume that the XML content is not dynamic ? (as in the program cabn expect book xml entries and not something else?).

Comment: Ok - it seems I have to roll up my sleeves on this one. I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

The task is straight forward, and the generic, turn of the century SAX Java interfaces will help you do the job. But you'll have to write it yourself.

If you spent 2 days just writing this, you'd have been done by now.

The hard part of the problem is that XML does not implicitly manifest itself in to maps of lists of maps like JSON does. JSON is simpler than XML.

For example, how do you know an element represents the root of a list vs a map? You can't know on the first encounter, you have to look ahead to decide that.

How do you capture element attributes? Do they just go in to the map like subelements?

These are questions as to why it's not straight forward to just have a generic utility for this.

But you know your XML, maybe you can have some "convention over configuration" (i.e. if the element name ends with an 's', odds are it's a list) to act as a heuristic during the marshaling process.

In the end, you simply need to track a few things on a stack, and decide what to do with the data and you walk the XML tree. The simple question is "Now that I have the element name, and it's data, what do I do with it?" Append it to my current map? Append it to my current list? Answer that question in the few case is comes up, and you're done. It's not difficult, but decisions have to be made that only you can make.

Comment: You're right - and I'm willing to make these decisions ;) What I'm curious in is, that there already exists already a language solving these problems: The JiBX binding.xml http://jibx.sourceforge.net/start.html. The only thing missing is, that it shouldn't be mapped to Java objects - it should be mapped directly to the database. Isn't there anything like this out there? :(

Comment: How is "If you spent 2 days just writing this, you'd have been done by now." helpful for anyone asking a question they're even struggling to formulate?